# Can't find a guide for building my own SWT dylibs

Tags: java, compilation, java-native-interface, swt, eclipse-rcp

I don't know how exactly this problem is to be tackled but I have an Eclipse RCP (indigo) application which used to be deployed on Mac (10.6.8) Snow Leopard that must now be deployed on Mac (10.14.3) Mojave.

Our team, out of the options of VM-ing the app, migrating up the Eclipse RCP  version (which due to the behemoth of an app we're dealing with would have led us hoplessly out of our time constraints), and keeping the app as is but simply providing a compatible SWT platform, chose the final option.

The idea being that SWT is the only real thing causing this Java app to not run when changing target platform.

the thing is we'd need an SWT targeted to Mac 10.14 and also answers Mac 10.6 calls.

Ergo a version that doesn't exist. (the end goal here, being to bundle our `.dylib`s with our project)

As my online searches have come up short I'd like to know what the procedure is for accomplishing this.

Here's what I **did** find :

https://wiki.eclipse.org/SWT/Devel/Gtk/Dev_guide#SWT_source_code_and_binary_repositories

https://wiki.eclipse.org/SWT/Developer_Guide

but I think they are trying to address how to develop **with** SWT not **how to develop and build** SWT.

also since I've never done anything like this I'm not sure I'm completely off the mark. is it SWT I'm aiming to build? is it JNI? is it os.java?

Comment: Those links are about developing and building SWT. But if you mean you want an SWT that supports both Cocoa and Carbon I think that would be extremely hard.

Comment: thanks! harder than migrating RCP upwards. knowing that Indigo was pre-major rehaul?

Comment: I have no idea, some old RCPs migrate without a problem, others have lots of problems especially if they are using internal APIs. It might be possible to use an SWT from a newer Eclipse and have one build for the old macOS and a different build for current macOS.